# AFNetworking changing json number to incorrect string

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm making a call using AFHTTPSessionManager:

```
//HTTP GET
[self GET:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, id responseObject) {

    blockOnSuccess(self,responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, NSError * error) {
    [self logFailure: error url: path];
    blockOnFailure(self,error);

}];
```

The json responseObject, viewed in Charles Proxy, has this value:

```
"sellingPrice": 9.95
```

The response from AFHTTPSessionManager, printed to the console, has this value:

```
sellingPrice = "9.949999999999999";
```

I'm having trouble understanding why it is changing the number and value type. Anyone run into this before and have an answer?

Comment: Update: This is happening with NSURLSession too...

Answer (score 0):

The print function is converting the numbers to strings and losing point precision. Sorry AFNetworking!

```
(lldb) print responseObject[@"variants"][0][@"sellingPrice"]
```

(__NSCFNumber *) $0 = 0x00006000024c9c60 (double)9.95

```
(lldb) po responseObject[@"variants"][0][@"sellingPrice"]
```

9.949999999999999